# Is Async Await violates MVC for sails 1.0?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, sails.js

I have a question about the Sails 1.0 framework.

Sails is now using `async` and `await` technique, but previously it was just callbacks.

Which is the best to use nowadays?
What are the advantages and disadvantages of each?
Does using `async` and `await` violate the MVC flow of Sails?

Comment: Actually I need sort of explanation, if a programmer is new with sails 1.0.
then how to approach with a proper way?
what will the parameters have to keep in mind to decide which technique is better to use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Async / await offers two main advantages:

1) With callbacks, unhandled errors will crash the process and bring the whole server down, which won't happen with async / await.

2) The code with async / await is cleaner because there is not the potential to have to deal with deeply nested callbacks.

There shouldn't be anywhere in your sails project where you are forced to use callbacks.

Comment: Re #1, actually unhandled rejections are going to crash the process as well. Promises do however make it a lot easier to handle the errors.